# Xquery return multiple values instead of one: For loop in xquery in osb

Tags: soap, xquery, soapui, soa, osb

Containers element should not repeat..

1. Under containers  the loop should repeat
   Example:

```
"Containers":
[
   {
      "I'd":"2",
      "Name":"sai",
      "Age":"23"
   },
   {
      "I'd":"3",
      "Name":"Kumar",
      "Age":"25"
   }
]
```

Note: only child items has to repeat but not containers.

How can we handle in xquery pls help on this,,, I have used for loop but containers is repeating...

Comment: Pls provide me the solution..how to handle it in OSB 12c.. xquery

Comment: When I have written xquery containers is repeating for second block

Comment: can you share what query and bow you writing loop

Comment: Okay I will share the code.  Which I have written

Comment: <containers>{for $containers in $input return <I'd>{(data($containers/ID)}<name>{(data($containers/NAME)}<age>{(data($containers/AGE)}}</containers>

Comment: I have written like above

Comment: Iam getting syntax error > is unexpected for "Name"

Comment: Note: in the above condition I have missed </I'd>, </age>,</name>

Comment: the data set is a JSON file and the xquery written for XML format

Comment: By using mfl I am converting text to xml and by using nxsd iam converting xml to json..

Comment: Pls let me know if you need any further information

Comment: so this operation younare trying to apply on converted  xml?

Comment: Yes..... I am applying on converted xml

Comment: Can.. you provide some logic.. with for loop that it has to return containers only one time

Comment: hope it is not too much to ask , can you also provide your xml

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an xml something like this

```
<root>
 <containers>
     <Id>1</Id>
     <Name>First Name</Name>
     <Age>11</Age>
  </containers>
  <containers>
     <Id>2</Id>
     <Name>Second Name</Name>
     <Age>12</Age>
  </containers>
</root>
```

Try executing the given xquery

```
<root>{
  for $x in //container
   return <containers>
   <Id>{data($x/Id)}</Id> 
    <Name>{data($x/Name)}</Name>
    <Age>{data($x/Age)}</Age>
   </containers>
  }<root>
```

the output will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<containers>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>First Name</Name>
      <Age>11</Age>
</containers>
<containers>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Name>Second Name</Name>
      <Age>12</Age>
  </containers>
</root>
```

and when you convert this to Json it will give you desired output
[Sample Json conversion - online](https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson)

```
{
    "root": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "Id": "1",
                "Name": "First Name",
                "Age": "11"
            },
            {
                "Id": "2",
                "Name": "Second Name",
                "Age": "12"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your Question is incorrect . if <containers> is a parent tag in that case automatically json converter will convert it to json array

Comment: Can you remove that <td> </td> and excute it.. and provide the output.. we will see wat it comes

Comment: Thanks for your help..i will execute it and let you know